# Inserted Values not inserted at index 1

Tags: mysql, sql

I've just started using SQL, and my knowledge is very limited on it so apologies if this seems like a stupid question.

I've tried to insert values into my table in phpmyadmin, and for some reason the data is being populated at index 27, not at index 1.

Here is the query:

```
INSERT into charge (ElecCharge)  
SELECT (ec.ElecEnergy* tp.ElecUnitRate 

        + tp.ElecStandingCharge) 
        AS TariffID
FROM energyconsumption ec INNER JOIN 
tariffplan tp ON ec.TariffID= tp.id
WHERE Date = CURDATE()
```

And this is  the output:

[image]

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: What version of SQL are you using (SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL etc)?

Comment: Have you deleted rows in the table? Or is it just the sorting that's not on the ID?

Comment: Hi @RichBenner, I'm using MySQL

Comment: Hi @MagnusEriksson, I have deleted the rows previously, my main concern is that the data is not being populated on row 1, rather, its jumping straight to row 27.

Comment: But rows 1 - 7 already exists? And if you delete rows, the auto increment doesn't get reset, it stays the same, so if you have index 1-10, delete them all and insert a new, it will get index 11.

Comment: @NoobCoder You're using an `INSERT` statement, so it will add a new record to the table.  There is already a record with `Id` `1` either way, so nothing is going to be added there regardless.  When you `INSERT` into a table with an auto-incrementing ID, it adds after where the last record was.  In this case, since you deleted some records, it inserts at `27`.  This is not an issue, as this identity column is merely there to be a unique identifier for the row.  If you are relying on this being in a specific order, you should add another column, as that's not its purpose.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Yes, it does, but Null is like the default value, I mean, shouldnt data be populated at row 1? It just looks like its skipped rows 1-7 and continued from previous deleted rows. Hope that make sense!

Comment: @Siyual Ah I think I understand. If i want to populate a value at row 1 I will need to set the data as opposed to Insert the data

Comment: @NoobCoder A row of `NULL` values is still a row.  You can't `INSERT` overtop of it.  You can `UPDATE` it if you wish.

Comment: No, if the row exists, it exists and you must do an "update" for it do get new values.

Comment: @NoobCoder Correct - you'll need to use an `UPDATE` statement instead of an `INSERT` statement.

Comment: @Siyual  thanks! I understand now

Comment: Why is the ID field so important, in this case? If it is, if kinda feels like a code smell.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Cheers!

Comment: don't mess with auto_incs. Many have come before with such notions and it never seems to end pretty. And certainly don't renumber everything